# Some problems with gdal_translate to translate from GeoTIFF to 32 bit grayscale TIFF, exr or similar

Tags: dem, gdal-translate

I need 32 bit grayscale DEM map from GeoTIFF to crop it in Photoshop and use in 3D applications as height displacement map. I use Windows and have images copied in OSGeo4W Bin folder so there is no issues with paths.

`gdal_translate.exe -if GTiff input.tif output.tiff` works but in practical sense it gives me the same image- pure white, which Photoshop or 3D software can't read.

gdal_translate.exe input.tif output.png works but is gives a warning that it is 8 bit,...
The image is not pure white, it has some gradient but still not it.

What would be working line to do it?

Any other good 32-bit supported format Photoshop or game engine could read?

---

I am not a GIS professional to know a lot about that. I just need it for 3d graphics. 32 bit float height maps are more precise as 8 bit jpegs. Source image is 32 bit GeoTif.

Image 1 is gdalinfo on input image.
Image 2 is what I need, that is what it needs to look like in Photoshop or similar software, when I open it. It needs to be it 32 bit, because  qgis exports give me staircase, like in 8 bit images. I don't know how would I translate GeoTiff to look like image 2 with help of gdal_translate. Desired file formats: 32 bit float exr, tiff or that ones, that ordinary photo editing software would see as it is in picture 2.

---

Results of gdalinfo input.tif -stats is in picture 3.
As I understand it 8 bits can represent range 0—255 (256 values). That is why there is banding(staircase) problem.

16 bits can represent range of 0 - 65535. That would be way better for what I need. 32bits even better if it is possible. People in 3d graphics say use 32 bit displacement maps. I have plenty of 32 bit exr float displacement maps from 3d sofware, it is better than 16 bits, tiny difference but it is. Photoshop can show 32 bit tiff maps, but can't understand GeoTif, some work on data has to be done to show that range in grayscale.

The thing is how to use gdal_translate to use geotiff data to show that larger range at least (0 -65535). The min max ranges are in float decimal values and not integers.

I had success with:

gdal_translate -scale -ot Byte input.tif output2.tiff -co COMPRESS=LZW

Warning 1: for band 1, nodata value has been clamped to 0, the original value being out of range.

That gives me 8 bit image, because -scale uses 0-255 default range. I need 16 bits at least.

I tried:
gdal_translate -scale [0 65555 [1158.209 3878.213]] -ot Float32 input.tif output.tiff

It doesn't work, I don't understand how to do it.

---

Issue is solved.

In source geotiff files contrast is extremely on one spectrum so you see it as white.

3d software(3ds max, Gaea) reads source geotiff and that displacement works, without banding.

If you want to see the image using gdal in 16 bit PNG range:

gdal_translate -ot UInt16 -of PNG input.tif output.png

That works nicely and you can see the source image.

Simpler solution is to use Photoshop.
Original file will be seen as white in 32 bit mode. If you want to see it you use HDR toning and that will change the contrast. That may also change values between elevations and compared to real world it will become innacurate.

You can convert source to 16 bit and use hdr toning as well.

Most accurate is using source(even if you can't see the gradient) in 3d software and adjust there. For cropping you can use hdr toning in photoshop as 1 layer to see what to crop and what not.

That is it.

[image: Input_image_info]
[image: What I need, but in 32 bit float format.]

[image: image 3]

Comment: Please try to clarify what you mean in your previous question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/470442/software-to-convert-from-geotiff-to-32-bit-grayscale-dem-image. For example, by 32-bit, do you mean Int32 or Float32? Could you give a link to some DEM that is in the desired format? BTW your current gdal_translate command effectively makes a copy of the source tif.

Comment: Part of the problem here is an apparent lack of understanding about that which you are requesting. Digital elevation models (DEMs) are generally 16-bit elevation values (if the delta between min and max is small, the units might be changed, e.g., decimeter or centimeter). 32-bit (signed or not) integer makes no sense whatsoever for a DEM *or* for a "grayscale" (too many discrete values). This makes this likely to be an XY Problem, so please take a step back and ask the Question that your 32-bit grayscale is intended to solve.

Comment: This seems the same question as [Software to convert from GeoTIFF to 32-bit grayscale DEM image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/470442/software-to-convert-from-geotiff-to-32-bit-grayscale-dem-image)

Comment: You have already a 32-bit image and QGIS can show it as you wish. Your problem is not in the image. Your issue is that by default Photoshop does not *show* the image in the same way than QGIS does. And that happens because the histogram of a 32-bit DEM is very biased. Read for example this tutorial http://cat-star.org/SOCO/PROCESSING/contrast.html. With `gdalinfo input.tif -stats` you can see the actual data range that is used in your DEM data. Is is certainly much narrower than the full range that can be covered with 32 bit.

Comment: Thank you for the statistics. They show that the data in the DEM is between 1158 and 3378 meters. The maximum value of Float32 is 3.4028235 × 10^38, thus much higher than 3378. The histogram stretch means that minimum value 1158 is presented as 0 on the computer screen and max value 3378 as 255 (or vice versa). You have range, but all your data are in the low end of the range. And you used `scale` values in wrong order. https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-scale `-scale [<src_min> <src_max> [<dst_min> <dst_max>]]`.

Comment: "A float is a floating-point number, which means it is a number that has a decimal place. Floats are used when more precision is needed." Min 1158.209  and max 3878.213 have decimal points so there is more precision from source 32 bit Geotiff than just simple integers. You rounded floats to integers.

Comment: I know, I was lazy with typing the decimals. They are off-topic when it comes to your contrast problem.